В битрикс24 скачивается файл "загрузка" при переходе во вкладку crm
Всем привет, при переходе во вкладку crm в Битрикс24 - скачивается файл загрузка

Возникают мысли, что дело тут в контроллере какого-нибудь класса, но вот в каком - неизвестно, кто сталкивался  с таким- какое решение помогло?
/crm/lead/?redirect_to - при переходе скачивается файл,
если убрать параметр ?redirect_to - то нормально переходит
